# How to join twice from same table. Group by same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a litte problem here. I want to join twice from the same table, and group by a common value.
Here is the dataset (from table Voucher):

```
Date (dd/mm/yyyy)   Amount
--------------------------
01.01.2010          1.000
15.01.2010          2.000
01.03.2010          3.000
01.03.2010          4.000
01.05.2010          5.000
01.01.2011          1.000
01.02.2011          2.000
01.04.2011          3.000
15.04.2011          4.000
01.05.2011          5.000
```

The result should be like this:

```
Month   Amount 2010   Amount 2011
---------------------------------
1       3.000         1.000
2                     2.000
3       7.000
4                     7.000
5       5.000         5.000
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Given your other questions, I'd guess SQL Server. Have you not learnt yet that if you're asking an SQL question, you need to tell us which RDBMS you're using?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm always improving (I hope) - will do better next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines will work for this case:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(month,[Date]) as Month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,[Date]) = 2010 THEN Amount END) as [Amount 2010],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,[Date]) = 2011 THEN Amount END) as [Amount 2011]
FROM
    Voucher
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(month,[Date]) as Month
```

For other situations, you might want to look into [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

`Date` is a really poor name for a column.

Comment: Tablename is Voucher as written in OP, but no biggie :)
Will try this out, thanks

Answer (score -2):

You have to give the tables different names like in this example:

```
SELECT Fruit1, F1FruitName = F1.FruitName, F1FruitCost = F1.FruitCost,
Fruit2, F2FruitName = F2.FruitName, F2FruitCost = F2.FruitCost FROM T1
JOIN T2 F1 ON Fruit1 = F1.Fruit_ID
JOIN T2 F2 ON Fruit2 = F2.Fruit_ID
```

The concrete syntax depends on your database system.